# Subtract current Year from a SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, oracle11g

How to subtract the current year from a table.

I have a table with a column `VehicleYear`. So I need to subtract only the current year from the `VehicleYear` to get the `VehicleAge`.

I tried the following query but it did not work since the `SYSDATE` seems to reflect the date when the row was added.

```
SELECT V. VEHICLENAME, (SYSDATE - V.VEHICLEYEAR) AS CURRENTAGE
FROM VEHICLE V
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query to subtract year from two dates

```
SELECT VEHICLENAME, 
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM VehicleYear) AS CURRENTAGE
FROM VEHICLE;
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4abc5/4)